# Load a urdf/xml file as rosparm from a c++ ros node

Tags: c++, rosnode, ros-kinetic, rosparam, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) tutorial. But it dosent show how to load a xml/urdf file as a rosparam.
Specifically, I want to set "robot_description" parameter from a c++ ros node not from a launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281545/load-a-urdf/xml-file-as-rosparm-from-a-c++-ros-node/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2018-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-01**:
How about using a launch file?

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-02-01**:
I have mentioned it clearly in the question that I am not looking to set the parameter from a launch file. It is not suitable for my purpose.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-01**:
Yeah, guess I missed that. Why not?

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-02-01**:
The reason is that I get the 'robot_name' from a rostopic inside the ros node and then I need to load the appropriate urdf file as parameter:"robot_description", depending on the robot_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:

Finally, this is how im doing it. You just need to read urdf file as a text file and store its content in a string and then set the string as a parameter

```
// Parse the urdf/xml file
std::string urdf_file_name = "/home/.../urdf_file_name.urdf"
std::ifstream f(urdf_file_name); 
std::stringstream ss;
ss << f.rdbuf();

// Set param
nh.setParam("robot_description", ss.str());
```

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-02**:
If you're not actually using the parsed urdf, why use tinyxml? A urdf is just a text file.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-02-05**:
@gvdhoorn I didnt realize this. I'll try to read urdf file as a simple text file and will update my answer if that works

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-02-12**:
@gvdhoorn you were absolutely correct. Thanks for your input.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2018-04-01**:
@vacky11 Could you please mention what is asset_urdf? Thanks.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-05-22**:
@NiranjanDeshpande it is the urdf file name  that needs to be set as a ros parameter. I will update my answer so that its intuitive

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
Can you please update your full code.
I code it like you, but there comes an error that 'youbot_arm' was not declared in this scope.
youbot_arm is the name of my urdf file.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
If I code it this way:

std::ifstream u ("/home/.../youbot_arm.urdf");

It cannot open the file.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-06-04**:
@JonasG I have updated my answer. Hope that helps!

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
@vacky11 I code it like that. Then I use the rdf_loader for initalization of my robot_model object and it give me an error.
Error document empty.
Unable to parse URDF.
The class
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning/html/classrdf__loader_1_1RDFLoader.html#ace79b92f5a219c0b52b28cdf309f701

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
With which function do you use the urdf from the parameter server?

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-06-04**:
@JonasG Do you mean which function I use to get a parameter from parameter server? I think something else might be wrong in your code. It will be easier for me understand the problem if you can share your code if that's possible

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/293155/cmakelisttxt/
There is a part of my code.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-06-04**:
@JonasG I just changed the third-last line in your code to `rdf_loader::RDFLoader robot_model(su.str(), ss.str());` and edited the path of urdf and srdf file. And the code works well. Make sure there arent any typos in the path of your urdf and srdf file. I think thats where the problem is.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-04**:
@vacky11
thank you very much, that was the point. Now it works.
I am so glad that you helped me out. ;)

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-07**:
@vacky11 do you have any experience of using a kdl plugin with moveit, for solving inverse kinematics with the setFromIK function?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-07**:
@JonasG: can I please ask you to keep things on-topic? Your comment has no bearing on the topic in this Q&A. Soliciting support from 'random' ROS Answers users is also not very nice.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-07**:
@gvdhoorn sure. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy parameter API:
http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server

roscpp parameter API:
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server

---

rospy example (note, I have not tried running this code):

```
import rospy


rospy.init_node('my_node_name')

# Open .urdf and save contents as str
urdf_filename = "robot.urdf"
urdf_string = None
with open(urdf_filename) as urdf_file:  
    urdf_string = urdf_file.read()  

# Load urdf_string onto parameter server
if urdf_string is not None:
    rospy.set_param('robot_description', urdf_filename)

# Check
if not rospy.has_param('robot_description'):
    rospy.login("Cannot find 'robot_description' on parameter server")
else:
    urdf_string_param = rospy.get_param('robot_description')
    rospy.login(urdf_string_param )
```

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-02-01**:
@josephcoombe
Thanks for your answer but Im looking for c++ implementation. Can you please give me a example for the same in c++?

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-02-01**:
@vacky11 I've updated my answer with a link to the roscpp equivalent.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-05-22**:
Hey. I am looking for that c++ implementation too. I don't know how to make a string out of my urdf.file. Can you please help me out? The rest of the code is clear.

Thanks

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-05-22**:
@JonasG, see @vacky11's [answer above](https://answers.ros.org/question/281545/load-a-urdfxml-file-as-rosparm-from-a-c-ros-node/?answer=281567#post-id-281567).

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-05-22**:
But I don't know what is meant with asset_urdf. I tried this but it doesn't work.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2018-05-22**:
@JonasG it is urdf file name.